# UIIMage view rotating by less than 90degrees

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode3.2

I have some code which supposedly should rotate the image by 45 degrees but in practice does not work it just flashes up about 10 times the size and disappears.

And when the same code is run but with the angle changed from 45 to 90 everything works fine. After looking through pages of similar questions I have found that other people are experiencing problems with rotating by 45 degrees but none are the same and none of the solutions help me.

So I was wondering if anybody could enlighten me?
Here is the code:

```
image.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((M_PI*45)/180);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
     image.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0.785398163);
```

In case you were wondering what the strange  0.785398163 value was, it is 45 degrees converted into radians. You can find degrees to radians and vice versa calculators on the internet.

Comment: also you have tagged Xcode 3.2
the newest is 4.3 just so you know

Comment: i do no but you can only download it with the latest mac software update i think and so i cant get it. but thanks anyway.

Comment: No need to calculate on Internet - radians = 45 / 180 * M_PI;

Comment: @iago849 sure, better!